# Rails: Find records in nested HABTM relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: Category and Post, they are joined through categories_posts table. Category can have subcategories via `category_id` field, which relevant to `id` of parent category field. Post can have multiple categories (both parent category and subcategory, or only one subcategory for example).

Category:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
has_many :categories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "category_id"
belongs_to :category, class_name: "Category"
```

Post:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
has_and_belongs_to_many :get_categories, class_name: 'Category'
```

All working fine, I can get posts for one specific category:

`Category.find(params[:id]).posts`

but can't get posts for category with own subcategories, something like this:

`` Category.where('`id` = :id OR `category_id` = :id', :id => params[:id]).posts ``

Rails console returns: `undefined method 'posts' for #<Category::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000110f9be40>`

I wrote right SQL query for this, but I need to compose the same query within Rails 4 by ActiveRecord.

`SELECT DISTINCT posts.* FROM posts INNER JOIN categories_posts ON posts.id = categories_posts.post_id WHERE categories_posts.category_id IN (3,10) ORDER BY posts.date DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the posts relation that belongs to a instance of a category on an array of category instances. You can just add a `.includes(:posts)` if you want to eager load posts. I'm not sure what your end use is but that is the problem.

However if you want to load all the posts that have that category or subcategory do it from the `Post` model like so: `Post.includes(:categories).where('categories.id = :id OR categories.category_id = :id, id: params[:id]).references(:categories)`